# cURL : (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: api, curl, sinatra

I am writing a remote API to handle some backend processes and my API typically takes about 30 seconds to complete the operation (I am fine with the wait time, it is an internal process). When I make a cURL call to the API, I get the following message `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. 
I need the cURL to wait for the response, `-m` and `connect-timeout` do not seem to help.

Additional information : I am using Sinatra for the backend API

Comment: Have you tested an additional means of HTTP request to see if you get a response? IE. (Mechanize/HTTParty ruby gems)

Comment: I did not try Mechanize/HTTParty. I did try the rest client to check the response and I do get it

Comment: I try It with `get "/"; sleep(30); "response"; end` an just use curl without any additional parameter and it work fine so it's not curl or sinatra you should check your code, your application server, your proxy, your what ever is between curl and your application

Comment: @Sir l33tname: Thanks, I did check for that before posting here, it was the same. 
I realized that Thin Application Server, which I was using for Sinatra has a default timeout of 30 seconds. I fixed that and it works like a charm.

Comment: nice :) I add it as answer, please accept it for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try It with `get "/"; sleep(30); "response"; end` an just use curl without any additional parameter and it work fine.

This mean normally it's not sinata or curl. It's something between like a proxy with timeout, a application server or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and traced it to be an issue with my proxy settings. Specifically I'm using TSOCKS to send everything to a socks proxy. Disabling TSOCKS allowed curl to work. Specifying the socks proxy with the curl command resolved the issue.

eg. curl --proxy socks5h://192.168.0.5:8111 http://webserver.com/file.ext